# AngularJS create new scope from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, isolate-scope

I don't really understand why this piece of code works the way it does.

I call my service and get the expected data returned. I wish to store the pictures seperately, as I need to modify the array and parse it differently to new scopes. The thing I don't understand is, that as I now have created 2 scopes, product and productPictures - why are these still linked?

If I use Lodash to _.sort() productPictures, then the Images object inside scope.Product will also be altered, however I do not want this happen, and I don't know how to isolate the $scope.productPictures. I tried handling the scopes as simple js variables such as var product; and var productPictures, but as I set their data according to the response from the service, they are still linked.

```
$api.productpage.query({
    id: parseInt($stateParams.productId)
}, function (data) {
    $scope.product = data[0];

    $scope.productPictures = data[0]['Images'];
});
```

Am I overlooking something super trivial? Should I rather manage the product images in a seperate service request?

Answer (score 5):

Objects are passed by reference in javascript. It means that in this code

```
$scope.product = data[0];
$scope.productPictures = data[0]['Images'];
```

`$scope.productPictures` points to the same object (I guess this is array in your case) as `data[0].Images`.

To overcome this issue you need to clone object instead of just reference. You might want to check [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) method:

```
$scope.productPictures = angular.copy(data[0].Images);
```

Comment: I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your extremely fast answer. Everything works wonders now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You create two variables in the scope not two scope.

Object are passed by reference so if you modify one it modidy the other.
Maybe try to clone the object

**edit use angular.copy() instead of jquery.extend()**

```
function myclone ( obj){
   return jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);  
}
```

Comment: OP asked about angular, why do you use a jQuery function?

Comment: angularjs use jquery lite. 
didn't know the angular.copy() function thanks